# How to set a NSString value when a certain selectedSegmentIndex has been selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control which when touched logs which selectedSegmentIndex has been selected. However it outputs `null` for the             `self.sessoField.text;`

any idea how to resolve this?

thanks

here's the console output from the following:

```
2013-10-24 11:00:11.131 [3628:60b] gender is (null) 1
2013-10-24 11:00:40.179 [3628:60b] gender is (null) 0
2013-10-24 11:00:41.546 [3628:60b] gender is (null) 1
```

.

```
- (IBAction)genderSelectButton:(id)sender {

    if (self.segmentedControlGender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        self.sessoField.text = @"m";
        NSLog(@"gender is %@ %d",self.sessoField.text,self.segmentedControlGender.selectedSegmentIndex);

    } else if(self.segmentedControlGender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        self.sessoField.text = @"f";
        NSLog(@"gender is %@ %d",self.sessoField.text,self.segmentedControlGender.selectedSegmentIndex);

    }
}
```

The sessoField has been declared in the .h as:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField * sessoField;
```

Comment: Did you make sure that sessoField is not nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your textfield is not nil and then Try like this :-

```
NSLog(@"gender is %@ %d",self.sessoField.text,self.segmentedControlGender.selectedSegmentIndex);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField * sessoField;

should be 

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField * sessoField;
```

Comment: @micantox why not true?

Comment: It is declared as an IBOutlet, which suggests that it should be an outlet. Outlets don't need to be declared as strong (although you can), as they are already retained by the view hierarchy.